# Material Design App Slicing - Android

Tags: interface-design, android, google-material-design

As we all know, Google have released a material design UI/UX platform for developers.
What are the image sizes that I have to follow to slice them for the various resolutions of android devices?

Comment: You should check [units / measurements](https://material.google.com/layout/units-measurements.html) and some [device metrics](https://design.google.com/devices/) to have a better grasp of how to slice the assets.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581649/about-android-image-and-asset-sizes

Comment: also this calculator might help http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/